# CSS Shadows only on bottom sides of div

Tags: html, css

How can I create shadows like this using CSS3: [image]

I have tried playing around with:

```
box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px -6px #919191;
```

Unfortunately it does not turn out the way I want it.

Comment: http://cssdeck.com/labs/different-css3-box-shadows-effects ?

Comment: @Fabrizio, look at the image..

Comment: @Mr.Alien post your comment as an answer and I will accept it! Thanks!

Comment: I think it won't be appropriate to answer the question as 1) It's not my code so I don't like to copy (even if I credit him) and secondly it will be just a link only answer so if you want then just flag a mod to close your question else people will keep posting random answers here :) and you welcome, glad it helped you

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```css
.box {
 width:70%;
 height:200px;
 background:#FFF;
 margin:40px auto;
}
.effect2
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect2:before, .effect2:after
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.effect2:after
{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box effect2"></div>
```

from [http://cssdeck.com/labs/different-css3-box-shadows-effects ][1]